# Statement true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I am attempting to evaluate the validity of this statement and I believe I have come up with an appropriate counter example. Could you please give me some feedback on whether my thinking is correct, or where I may have had faulty logic? Thanks in advance!

If $f \in \mathcal R[a,b]$, where $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and $a<b$, and $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ for $x\in [a,b]$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$ must be true for any $x\in (a,b)$.

> The only idea I have which might possibly be a counter-example is to construct a piecewise function. The one I have in mind is something like
>
> $$f(t)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } -1\leq t < 0\\
> t \text{ if } 0\leq t\leq 1\\
> 4 \text{ if } 1<t\leq 2\end{cases}$$
>
> This is integrable over the interval $[-1,2]$ and the anti-derivative $F(x)$ is given by
>
> $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } -1\leq x < 0\\
> \frac{x^{2}}{2} \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq 1\\
> 4x+\frac{7}{2} \text{ if } 1<x\leq 2\end{cases}$$
>
> But $F$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, so $F'(x)\ne f(x)$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal R[a,b]$?

Comment: This is pretty standard notation for "Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$" or so I thought, now you're making me doubt myself.

Comment: Yes, it is true that F' is not equal to f.  That does not violate the "fundamental theorem of Calculus" because f is not continuous at x= 1.

Comment: @user247327 I can see why you jump to the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I've understood that only if $f$ is continuous at some $c\in[a,b]$ can you really jump to the conclusion that $F$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)$. Here I have a clear case where $F$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: You have a typo in your $F(x)$, it must be $4x - \frac{7}{2}$ in the last case. Your counterexample works, but is more complicated than necessary. Any jump discontinuity of $f$ leads to a point where $F'(x)$ doesn't exist (if the left-hand and right-hand limits of $f$ at $x$ differ) or $F'(x) \neq f(x)$ (if the left-hand and right-hand limits of $f$ at $x$ coincide, but differ from $f(x)$).

Comment: @DanielFischer nice catch on the last case. I guess I could have generalized it as you did. Thanks!